# rails use routes/named helper in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Here is what I have. I have a action and I can see the route by rake routes

```
date_swimming_classschedules GET    /swimming/classschedules/date/:date(.:format) swimming/classschedules#date
```

I tried to generate the url in my view my using

```
'<%= date_swimming_classschedules(@date)%>'
```

I got an error message

```
undefined method `date_swimming_classschedules'
```

Something I am missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
date_swimming_classschedules_path(@date)
```

or

```
date_swimming_classschedules_url(@date)
```

Comment: THanks :) date_swimming_classschedules_path(@date) is exactly what I need

Answer (score 3):

You have to append `_path` to the named route.
do it like this.

```
date_swimming_classschedules_path(@date)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are missing `_path` on your method call. Do:

```
date_swimming_classschedules_path(@date)
```